# WinForms - Dynamically create textbox based on ComboBox selection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

I am trying to create a `TextBox` based on the selection on `ComboBox` dynamically based on the following steps:

First step (Select a source from `ComboBox`):

[image: 1st SS]

Second step (`Textbox` should appear based on `ComboBox.SelectedValue`):

[image: 2ND SS]

Last step (A new `ComboBox` should appear below):

[image]

I have created a `createTextBox` function using the following code:

```
public void createTextBox(int numPassenger)
{
    TextBox[] passengerBoxes = new TextBox[numPassenger];

    for (int u = 0; u < passengerBoxes.Count(); u++)
    {
        passengerBoxes[u] = new TextBox();
    }
    int i = 0;
    foreach (TextBox txt in passengerBoxes)
    {
        string name = "passenger" + i.ToString();

        txt.Name = name;
        txt.Text = name;
        txt.Location = new Point(244, 32 + (i * 28));
        txt.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can modify my current function to adapt to the mentioned steps? Additionally, how can I find the dynamically created `TextBox`?

Comment: In the combobox_selection_changed event you have to call the method, which creates the textboxes. the method should loop throug all controls and find comboboxes, which have value selected. for each of these a textbox should be created. `this.Controls` contains all controls on the winform. You can loop through the list.

Comment: Who's idea of using combobox to choose what you want to edit? Why not using a standard form, where you see and edit everything?

Comment: Best would be Create the Controls beforehand and show/hide on the base of your selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createTextBox(sender as ComboBox);
    }
    private void createTextBox(ComboBox cmb)
    {
        TextBox passengerBoxes = new TextBox();
        string name = cmb.Text;
        if (Controls.Find(name, true).Length == 0)
        {
            passengerBoxes.Name = name;
            passengerBoxes.Text = name;
            int textBoxCount = GetTextBoxCount();
            passengerBoxes.Location = new Point(244, 32 + (textBoxCount * 28));
            passengerBoxes.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(passengerBoxes);

            if (cmb.Items.Count != 1)//last item remaining then we should not create new combo box
            {
                ComboBox newCombo = new ComboBox
                {
                    Location = new Point(cmb.Location.X, 32 + ((textBoxCount + 1) * 28))
                };

                foreach (string str in cmb.Items)
                    if (cmb.Text != str)
                        newCombo.Items.Add(str);

                newCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

                this.Controls.Add(newCombo);
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Textbox Already for the selected source " + name);
    }

    private int GetTextBoxCount()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctl is TextBox) i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
```